# React Native / Native Base how to render a Picker on navbar?

Tags: react-native, native-base

How can I render a navbar (Header on NativeBase) with a Picker as a button, when I click on this button then the Picker will open as below:
[image]

I tried with the example but it seem the Picker not showing on the Header:

```
<Right>
  <View>
    <Picker
      mode="dropdown">
      <Item label="Wallet" value="key0" />
      <Item label="ATM Card" value="key1" />
    </Picker>
  </View>
</Right>
```

Comment: The issue you are facing, is added onto our GitHub Issues list.
Check [here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/880) for updates

Answer (score 0):

Just use [ToolbarAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid.html) instead

Answer (score 0):

{this._renderButtonBack(disableBack,onBack)}

```
<Title style={{alignSelf:'center', color:'white'}}>{title}</Title>

<Right style={{alignSelf:'center', color:'white'}}>
    <Button style={{backgroundColor:colors.pramiryColor, justifyContent:'flex-end',alignItems:'flex-end',
                    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },shadowColor: 'transparent',shadowOpacity: 0,
                    elevation: 0}}>
        <Picker
            mode="dropdown"
            iosHeader={iosHeader}
            iosIcon={<Icon name="ios-arrow-down-outline" />}
            style={{height:35,
                color:'white',
                width: Platform.OS === 'ios'? '30%':'35%', backgroundColor:colors.pramiryColor}}
            selectedValue={currentStatus}
            onValueChange={onStatusChanged}>
            {itemPickers}
        </Picker>
    </Button>
</Right>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally get a very close result using [react-native-material-dropdown](https://github.com/n4kz/react-native-material-dropdown)
Once imported and the data object has been set with the values you need (I used Save, Delete, Cancel), you can use the following code/settings

```
<Right>
  <Button transparent>
    <Icon name="md-more" style={{ color: '#fff' }} />
  </Button>
  <Dropdown
    label=""
    data={data}
    containerStyle={{
      opacity: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)',
      top: 4,
      right: -10,
      color: 'white',
      position: 'absolute',
      height: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 48 : 52,
      width: 70,
    }}
    pickerStyle={{
      marginTop: 60,
      marginRight: 40,
    }}
    overlayStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27)' }}
    dropdownOffset={{ top: 0, left: 0 }}
    dropdownPosition="1"
    itemColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, .87)"
    selectedItemColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, .87)"
  />
</Right>;
```